# Deploying Scrapy Spiders using a Twisted Server

Tags: python, bash, scrapy, twisted, scrapyd

I have `+20 scrapy crawlers` that I want to `deploy` manually from a browser `webpage`.
In order to achieve this, I have created a simple `twisted server` that executes in a shell process the following commands:

```
scrapyd-deploy default -p $project
curl http://127.0.0.1:6800/schedule.json -d project=$project -d spider=$spider
```

These commands are executed in `twisted` using `utils.getProcessOutput(scriptname)`. The two previous commands are inside the `script` given as a parameter.

When trying to execute the twisted server with `twistd -y <server.py>`, it gives the following error: `[Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): : got stderr: 'Packing version 1399464111\n'
]`.

Here is the `twisted` server's code:

```
#/usr/bin/python
from twisted.internet import utils, reactor
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.application import internet, service

class CrawlerResource(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    script = "./script2.sh"

    def render_GET(self, request):
        request.write("<pre>\n")
        deferred = utils.getProcessOutput(self.script)
        deferred.addCallback(lambda s: (request.write(s+"success!\n"), request.finish()))
        deferred.addErrback(lambda s: (request.write(str(s)), request.finish()))

        return server.NOT_DONE_YET



# factory: create a protocol for each connection
resource = CrawlerResource()
factory = server.Site(resource)

# application & service: run server in the background as a service
application = service.Application("Crawlers deployer")
service = internet.TCPServer(8000, factory)
service.setServiceParent(application)
```

What's causing this error (it isnt very verbose)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bytes on the child process's standard error stream are causing this.  `getProcessOutput` treats any standard error output as an error and fails the `Deferred`.

You might fix this by passing `errortoo=True` to `getProcessOutput`.  This makes it mix stdout and stderr together in the result instead of treating data on stderr as an error.

You can read about this behavior in the [getProcessOutput API documentation](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.utils.html#getProcessOutput).